# VBA Excel code needed to search open worksheet and print results to new worksheet through a userform

Tags: search, excel, userform, vba

I am new to VBA, but I am eager to learn! I have searched tirelessly for an answer to this question with little success.

Currently, I have created a command button to play a userform that has multiple search criteria for a large database. The userform searches the open worksheet and populates the remaining fields based on what information the user enters (name, type, email, source, donor information, last contact, etc). This is basically a user-friendly advanced lookup.

I need to be able to search any of the criteria, often producing multiple results, and have those multiple results print/paste to a new worksheet. Ideally, I would like to include a command button for "Search and View Results" on the current userform because I am creating this for some very tech-unfriendly folks.

If any of you have a code which I could input to a new command button I will place on the current userform to accomplish this task I would be so so grateful!

If you have other suggestions, I am totally open to those as well. I even considered having a button for lookup and a button for search and view results on the open workbook, but I still need all search criteria present.

So many thanks in advance!

Currently, I have this code in the userform:

```
 Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
 row_number = 0
 Do
 DoEvents
 row_number = row_number + 1
 item_in_review = Sheets("ULEC-Master-Consolidated.csv").Range("F" & row_number)
If item_in_review = TextBox1.Text Then
    TextBox2.Text = Sheets("ULEC-Master-Consolidated.csv").Range("H" & row_number)
    TextBox3.Text = Sheets("ULEC-Master-Consolidated.csv").Range("J" & row_number)
    TextBox4.Text = Sheets("ULEC-Master-Consolidated.csv").Range("N" & row_number)
    TextBox5.Text = Sheets("ULEC-Master-Consolidated.csv").Range("P" & row_number)
    TextBox6.Text = Sheets("ULEC-Master-Consolidated.csv").Range("Q" & row_number)
    TextBox7.Text = Sheets("ULEC-Master-Consolidated.csv").Range("R" & row_number)
    TextBox8.Text = Sheets("ULEC-Master-Consolidated.csv").Range("S" & row_number)
    ComboBox1.Text = Sheets("ULEC-Master-Consolidated.csv").Range("A" & row_number)
    ComboBox2.Text = Sheets("ULEC-Master-Consolidated.csv").Range("B" & row_number)
    ComboBox3.Text = Sheets("ULEC-Master-Consolidated.csv").Range("C" & row_number)
    TextBox9.Text = Sheets("ULEC-Master-Consolidated.csv").Range("D" & row_number)
    TextBox10.Text = Sheets("ULEC-Master-Consolidated.csv").Range("Y" & row_number)
    TextBox11.Text = Sheets("ULEC-Master-Consolidated.csv").Range("T" & row_number)
    TextBox12.Text = Sheets("ULEC-Master-Consolidated.csv").Range("U" & row_number)
    TextBox13.Text = Sheets("ULEC-Master-Consolidated.csv").Range("V" & row_number)
    TextBox14.Text = Sheets("ULEC-Master-Consolidated.csv").Range("W" & row_number)
    TextBox15.Text = Sheets("ULEC-Master-Consolidated.csv").Range("X" & row_number)
    End If

 Loop Until item_in_review = ""

 End Sub
```

*I repeat this code for each text box and combo box I have included. Additionally, I have a "clear form" button.

Comment: What does your existing macro look like?

Comment: @admdrew I just placed in some of the macro code. Let me know what more might be helpful!

Answer (score 0):

For the search functionality you want to build in, you may be able to leverage a search function I found on Ozgrid and use daily in my own coding.  I have marked page 2 of the post since the function was updated from the original post.  Hope this helps:

http://www.ozgrid.com/forum/showthread.php?t=27240&page=2

Comment: After looking at this, it wasn't working for me. I created the command button and tried to alter the syntax to match my worksheet with no success. Perhaps I don't know enough code. Any other advice? Is this even possible in Excel VBA?